# PresentViewController dismiss the current viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, video-streaming, presentviewcontroller

I am using [XCDYouTubeVideoPlayer](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) and when i want to present `videoPlayerViewController` it seems, it dismiss my current uiviewcontroller (view fades down) and present videoPlayerViewController and when i am done with video and click "Done" button, it will push previous view controller from the bottom again.

PresentViewControl is known as it is good to present view on the top by `keeping the existing view`, but in this case it doesn't and i can visually see view fades down when i present the other.

This is my code:

```
XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:@"9bZkp7q19f0"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
```

**Note:** I also tried to present with some other video controllers, only to test if issue is from this specific video player library but no. If i present some other non-video view it does not produce the issue. So, i suspect it is related to video view controllers.

Can anyone please help me on this, and share ideas on how to get rid of this problem when presenting a video view controller. Thank you.

Comment: A `UIViewController` should only present a single other UIViewController. The presented `UIViewController` can show it self a single other `UIViewController` if needed, but if you think about it, the "grand parent" one only shows one.

Comment: I only present one UIViewController which is videoViewController. And, when i click done on full screen video it is supposed to dismiss videoViewController, thats it. But in this case it also kinda again present previous view controller.

Comment: Did you tried something with the `unwind segue` ?If I'm understanding your problem you want to go back on your 1st Controller without reloading it completely? Right or not?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to go back and not reloading anything. Also i dont want to dismiss anything, only present on top of UI Controller.